# Docker - unable to run supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I try to install supervisor on my local docker container where I run php8.1 and laravel 9.
But I have following error:

```
'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log'
```

This is my config:
supervisor.conf

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
```

php dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.13-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        nano \
        libxslt1.1 \
        libxslt1-dev \
        unzip \
        git \
        gnupg \
        libpq-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        iputils-ping \
        supervisor \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    gd \
    mysqli pdo pdo_mysql  \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    
RUN echo "memory_limit='512M'" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-extra.ini;

ENV PHP_IDE_CONFIG "serverName=new_app"

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer --version=2.3.8 && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer

# Set timezone
RUN rm /etc/localtime \
    && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw /etc/localtime \
    && "date" \
    && printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "Europe/Warsaw"\n' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini \

RUN usermod -aG docker $USER
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

How can I fix it?

Regards.

Comment: Can you delete the supervisord setup, but in a second container, `docker run -d your-image php artisan queue:work`?  Usually running only one process in a container is a little easier to set up, manage, and scale.

Comment: 1. Try run supervisor as root (if container run as root)
2. on dockerfile create /var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log

Comment: any update on this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

### 1.

i saw these in your dockerfile, your file does not match,

```
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

i suggest to change to below:

```
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

### 2.

Add this to your dockerfile, to replace the original line, and try again. Good luck

```
RUN usermod -aG docker $USER &&\
    mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/logs &&\
    touch /var/www/html/storage/logs/worker.log
```